# Getting name based on max value of a column with NA removed in one liner

Tags: r, tibble

I'm trying to get the name of an animal who has the max value of rem sleep. This is what I'm doing right now but hoping for a better way that returns exact value.

```
msleep = ggplot2::msleep
msleep[order(msleep$sleep_rem, na.last=TRUE, decreasing=TRUE), ]
```

The above returns me the sorted data but it's hard to see in console in Rstudio. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to get the index of max value in 'sleep_rem' and use that to subset the 'name'

```
msleep$name[which.max(msleep$sleep_rem)]
#[1] "Thick-tailed opposum"
```

Answer (score 0):

For better viewing you can `arrange` the data and select only the interested columns -

```
library(dplyr)

msleep %>% arrange(desc(sleep_rem)) %>% select(name, sleep_rem)

# A tibble: 83 x 2
#   name                           sleep_rem
#   <chr>                              <dbl>
# 1 Thick-tailed opposum                 6.6
# 2 Giant armadillo                      6.1
# 3 North American Opossum               4.9
# 4 Big brown bat                        3.9
# 5 European hedgehog                    3.5
# 6 Thirteen-lined ground squirrel       3.4
# 7 Domestic cat                         3.2
# 8 Long-nosed armadillo                 3.1
# 9 Golden hamster                       3.1
#10 Golden-mantled ground squirrel       3  
# … with 73 more rows
```